# Задача по JS, нужен совет

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку создался элемент input и кнопка, но создает только кнопку, прошу помочь найти ошибку.

```
function f8() {
    let out = document.querySelector('.out-8');
    out.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="i-81"/>'
    out.innerHTML = '<button class="b-81"></button>'
}

function f81 () {

}

document.querySelector('.b-8').onclick = f8;
```

Comment: Давайте вместе подумаем. `o = 1; o = 2; console.log(o);` <- Что напечатает?

Comment: ну тогда как сделать чтобы создало елемент и кнопку за один клик

Comment: `a = 1; b = 2; o = ...;` Что написать вместо многоточия, чтобы в `c` оказалась сумма `a` и `b`?

Comment: я не понимаю как это мне поможет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы каждым следующим `innerHTML` затираете предыдущий. Правильно так:

```js
function f8() {
  let out = document.querySelector('.out-8');
  out.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="i-81" placeholder="input"/><button class="b-81">button</button>';
}

document.querySelector('.b-8').onclick = f8;
```

```css
.b-8 {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px red;
}

.out-8 {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-8"></div>
<div class="out-8"></div>
```

А ещё лучше [так](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
function f8() {
  let out = document.querySelector('.out-8');
  out.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<input type="text" class="i-81" placeholder="input"/>');
  out.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<button class="b-81">button</button>');
}

document.querySelector('.b-8').onclick = f8;
```

```css
.b-8 {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px red;
}

.out-8 {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-8"></div>
<div class="out-8"></div>
```

Comment: Как запретить при повторных кликах, следующие создания кнопок и input